# jQuery .animate working in Firefox but not Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery

I have a basic animation I am trying to get working at http://jsfiddle.net/5YrF2/3/

Everything works as expected in Firefox, but in Chrome or Internet Explorer the position of the animated object jumps to the bottom of the screen after the first animate command.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I have now created a new version of the animation with extra pipes at http://jsfiddle.net/5YrF2/6/

Everything works ok up until .block3 is animated, it is supposed to go right 10 pixels and then up 15 pixels.  Instead it does some strange wiggle.  Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Please format your JS so that it is readable.

Comment: @maxedison: there's a "TidyUp" button at the top just for you. :-)

Comment: @maxedison if you click the "Tidy Up" button, it will clean the formatting up - not that we shouldn't tidy up our own code, but if you want to see nicer formatting, it will handle it for you.

Comment: I have updated the link to the new tidy version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an absolutely positioned div, with no bottom set. Chrome & IE are working correctly in this case -- your second animation adds 10 to "bottom", which sets bottom to 0 (since it's unset) and animates it to 10. An absolutely-positioned div with a "bottom" of 10, and no top, will display 10 pixels from the bottom of the container.

Did you want the element to move "up"? If so, I'd say use top instead. (But you will have the same problem, since you also didn't have a top attribute set). I would get rid of "margin-left" and "margin-top" on your element and use top/left/etc. instead.

Comment: That seems to work correctly, I have updated the code at http://jsfiddle.net/5YrF2/5/ but now the problem is the animation starts too far left

Comment: Ignore me!  I've been staring at this for to long.  Changed absolute positioning to relative and now all is working fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Now I have changed things I have run into another issue, im sure its related to what we have discussed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/5YrF2/7/. I have added _position:relative_ to your container div, and changed your _margin-left_ and _margin-top_ values to _left_ and _top_, respectively. I think it is doing what you want, let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: Hi Elliot,  i am now faced with this issue http://jsfiddle.net/5YrF2/9/   -  The bullet on the right hand side fades in correctly, but after the other animation is complete it moves up somehow

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/5YrF2/11/. All of the blocks should be _position:absolute_. The bullet on the right hand side starts "up" and stays there, because it's top property is -12px. Changing this to something else should reposition it.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to animate the CSS "bottom" attribute, which can go wrong when it's not explicitly set in the first place. Try animating the "top" attribute instead and reverse the direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/5YrF2/4/

```
$.Deferred(function(dfr) {
    dfr.pipe(function() {
        return $(".block1").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({
            left: '+=600'
        }, 2500, "linear").animate({
            left: '+=10',
            top: '-=10'
        }, 100, "linear").animate({
            left: "+=27"
        }, 100, "linear").animate({
            left: '+=10',
            top: '+=10'
        }, 100, "linear").animate({
            left: "+=25"
        }, 100, "linear").fadeOut();
    }).pipe(function() {
        return $(".block1").css('left', '');
    }).pipe(function() {
        return $(".block1").delay(500).fadeIn();
    })
}).resolve();
```